# How to get values from JSON pojo

Tags: java, json, pojo

I am very new to JSON and jackson, currently I have pojo files and I am trying to get the data and store it in an array. for example I want to extract Network name and store it an array and later display or compare it with live site data.

here is the main pojo file -

```
    public class JsonGen{
        private String _type;
        private List cast;
        private List clips;
        private Common_sense_data common_sense_data;
        private String common_sense_id;
        private List crew;
        private String description;
        private List episodes;
        private Number franchise_id;
        private List genres;
        private String guid;
        private Images images;
        private boolean is_locked;
        private boolean is_mobile;
        private boolean is_parental_locked;
        private String kind;
        private List mobile_networks;
        private String most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
        private String name;
        private List networks;
        private List platforms;
        private List ratings;
        private String release_date;
        private List season_filters;
        private String slug;
        private String tms_id;

        public String get_type(){
            return this._type;
        }
        public void set_type(String _type){
            this._type = _type;
        }
        public List getCast(){
            return this.cast;
        }
        public void setCast(List cast){
            this.cast = cast;
        }
        public List getClips(){
            return this.clips;
        }
        public void setClips(List clips){
            this.clips = clips;
        }
        public Common_sense_data getCommon_sense_data(){
            return this.common_sense_data;
        }
        public void setCommon_sense_data(Common_sense_data common_sense_data){
            this.common_sense_data = common_sense_data;
        }
        public String getCommon_sense_id(){
            return this.common_sense_id;
        }
        public void setCommon_sense_id(String common_sense_id){
            this.common_sense_id = common_sense_id;
        }
        public List getCrew(){
            return this.crew;
        }
        public void setCrew(List crew){
            this.crew = crew;
        }
        public String getDescription(){
            return this.description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description = description;
        }
        public List getEpisodes(){
            return this.episodes;
        }
        public void setEpisodes(List episodes){
            this.episodes = episodes;
        }
        public Number getFranchise_id(){
            return this.franchise_id;
        }
        public void setFranchise_id(Number franchise_id){
            this.franchise_id = franchise_id;
        }
        public List getGenres(){
            return this.genres;
        }
        public void setGenres(List genres){
            this.genres = genres;
        }
        public String getGuid(){
            return this.guid;
        }
        public void setGuid(String guid){
            this.guid = guid;
        }
        public Images getImages(){
            return this.images;
        }
        public void setImages(Images images){
            this.images = images;
        }
        public boolean getIs_locked(){
            return this.is_locked;
        }
        public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
            this.is_locked = is_locked;
        }
        public boolean getIs_mobile(){
            return this.is_mobile;
        }
        public void setIs_mobile(boolean is_mobile){
            this.is_mobile = is_mobile;
        }
        public boolean getIs_parental_locked(){
            return this.is_parental_locked;
        }
        public void setIs_parental_locked(boolean is_parental_locked){
            this.is_parental_locked = is_parental_locked;
        }
        public String getKind(){
            return this.kind;
        }
        public void setKind(String kind){
            this.kind = kind;
        }
        public List getMobile_networks(){
            return this.mobile_networks;
        }
        public void setMobile_networks(List mobile_networks){
            this.mobile_networks = mobile_networks;
        }
        public String getMost_recent_full_episode_added_date(){
            return this.most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
        }
        public void setMost_recent_full_episode_added_date(String most_recent_full_episode_added_date){
            this.most_recent_full_episode_added_date = most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public List getNetworks(){
            return this.networks;
        }
        public void setNetworks(List networks){
            this.networks = networks;
        }
        public List getPlatforms(){
            return this.platforms;
        }
        public void setPlatforms(List platforms){
            this.platforms = platforms;
        }
        public List getRatings(){
            return this.ratings;
        }
        public void setRatings(List ratings){
            this.ratings = ratings;
        }
        public String getRelease_date(){
            return this.release_date;
        }
        public void setRelease_date(String release_date){
            this.release_date = release_date;
        }
        public List getSeason_filters(){
            return this.season_filters;
        }
        public void setSeason_filters(List season_filters){
            this.season_filters = season_filters;
        }
        public String getSlug(){
            return this.slug;
        }
        public void setSlug(String slug){
            this.slug = slug;
        }
        public String getTms_id(){
            return this.tms_id;
        }
        public void setTms_id(String tms_id){
            this.tms_id = tms_id;
        }

    }
```

here is the Network Pojo class -

```
 public class Networks{
        private String banner;
        private String description;
        private boolean is_locked;
        private String logo;
        private String name;
        private String network_analytics;
        private Number network_id;
        private String slug;
        private String thumbnail_url;
        private String url;

        public String getBanner(){
            return this.banner;
        }
        public void setBanner(String banner){
            this.banner = banner;
        }
        public String getDescription(){
            return this.description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description = description;
        }
        public boolean getIs_locked(){
            return this.is_locked;
        }
        public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
            this.is_locked = is_locked;
        }
        public String getLogo(){
            return this.logo;
        }
        public void setLogo(String logo){
            this.logo = logo;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getNetwork_analytics(){
            return this.network_analytics;
        }
        public void setNetwork_analytics(String network_analytics){
            this.network_analytics = network_analytics;
        }
        public Number getNetwork_id(){
            return this.network_id;
        }
        public void setNetwork_id(Number network_id){
            this.network_id = network_id;
        }
        public String getSlug(){
            return this.slug;
        }
        public void setSlug(String slug){
            this.slug = slug;
        }
        public String getThumbnail_url(){
            return this.thumbnail_url;
        }
        public void setThumbnail_url(String thumbnail_url){
            this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
        }
        public String getUrl(){
            return this.url;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url){
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
```

and here is my code through which I am  trying to extract the network names -

```
 public class util {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

            List<JsonGen> jsongenShow = null;
            String url1 = "http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/home/carousels/shows.json";
            getShowNWGopherParser(nwork, url1);
        }

    public static String[] getShowNWGopherParser (List<Networks> nwork, String url ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
        ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //objmapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        nwork = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<Networks>>() {});
        String [] shows = new String [nwork.size()]; 
        int i = 0;
        for(Networks element : nwork) {
            shows[i++]=element.getUrl();
            }
        for(int j =0; j<shows.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(shows[j]);

        }
        return shows;   
     }
    }
```

and here is the error -

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "networks" (class featureshows.Networks), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: , "logo", "slug", "name", "banner", "network_id", "url", "network_analytics", "description", "thumbnail_url", "is_locked"])
     at [Source: http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/home/carousels/shows.json; line: 1, column: 15] (through reference chain: featureshows.Networks["networks"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:568)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:650)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:830)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:310)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:112)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:226)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:203)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2563)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1789)
        at functions.util.getShowNWGopherParser(util.java:77)
        at functions.util.main(util.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're using a regular `List` interface for your list of networks instead of the generic version with the bounds for the expected type.

Try changing the field declaration from:

`private List networks;`

to

`private List<Networks> networks;`

While you're at it, it looks like you're using the regular `List` interface pretty much everywhere. You'll probably run into more issues if you don't convert them all to include the type you expect in the list.

Essentially, you're not providing enough information about the type of object you expect in the list for jackson to figure out what to populate it with. You can read more about generics here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html

**EDIT:**

It looks (from your comment) that you've already tried disabling checks for unknown properties, but try adding this annotation to your Networks class:

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: I changed   private List <Networks> networks; in JsonGen but still same error. :(

Comment: pojo files are auto generated from Jsongen.com . I have changed the code like this - URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
  ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Networks[] networks = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, Networks[].class);
  nwork = Arrays.asList(networks);. but now it's asking to add cast to Networks[] on the line nwork = Arrays.asList(networks);

Comment: with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) it's printing Show Names from JsonGen's getName method.

Comment: what do you mean printing? Try adding that annotation to both classes. Also, you can remove that business about the Networks[].class, I didn't realize that TypeReference had an anonymous inner class.

Comment: I have already added ignoreproperties on both the classes, but when I am printing the results in console , the result is not displaying network names rather name of the shows - URL -http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/home/carousels/shows.json

Comment: Rather than working with Network class function is fetching values from JsonGen class. and without annotations it's failing with same error. :(

Comment: It should need the annotation.. I think your jsongen did not do a great job for you. I would still advise converting to generics, and do use the annotation.

Comment: I am sure I am going to sound stupid , but if you can give me an example , that link is confusing me more, I am real newbie to jackson and pojo concept.